# Div grow up dynamically

Tags: php, html, css, yii, yii2

How can I avoid that div grow up dynamically in my view. I want to make different view display depends of what $type parameter I put into my action in Controller. But now it works strange, view doesn't display content but if condition is 2 or 3(Euro or RUR) view displays like div's are inside that view.

View:

```
<?php

/* @var $this yii\web\View */

use yii\helpers\Html;

$this->title = 'Курс валют';
?>
<div>

    <h2> Курс валют на сегодня</h2>
    <div class="banks">
        <h3>Банки:</h3>
        <h4>ПриватБанк</h4>
        <h4>НБУ</h4>
        <h4>МежБанк</h4>
        <h4>Черный рынок</h4>
    </div>
    <?php if($type == 'USA') {?>
    <div class="buy">
        <h3> Покупка </h3>
        <p><?php print_r($privatdata[2]["buy"])?></p>
        <p><?php print_r($nbudata[14]["rate"])?></p>
        <p><?php print_r($mejdata[0]["Buy"])?></p>
        <p><?php print_r($blackdata[0]["Buy"])?></p>
    </div>
    <div class="sale">
        <h3> Продажа </h3>
        <p><?php print_r($privatdata[2]["sale"])?></p>
        <p><?php print_r($nbudata[14]["rate"])?></p>
        <p><?php print_r($mejdata[0]["Sale"])?></p>
        <p><?php print_r($blackdata[0]["Sale"])?></p>
    </div>
    <div class="avg_rate">
        <h3>Средний курс на сегодня:</h3>
        <?php print_r($avgUSA)?>
    <?php }?>
    </div>

<?php if($type == 'Euro') { ?>
    <div class="buy">
        <h3> Покупка </h3>
        <p><?php print_r($privatdata[0]["buy"])?></p>
        <p><?php print_r($nbudata[23]["rate"])?></p>
        <p><?php print_r($mejdata[1]["Buy"])?></p>
        <p><?php print_r($blackdata[1]["Buy"])?></p>
    </div>
    <div class="sale">
        <h3> Продажа </h3>
        <p><?php print_r($privatdata[0]["sale"])?></p>
        <p><?php print_r($nbudata[23]["rate"])?></p>
        <p><?php print_r($mejdata[1]["Sale"])?></p>
        <p><?php print_r($blackdata[1]["Sale"])?></p>
    </div>
    <div class="avg_rate">
        <h3>Средний курс на сегодня:</h3>
        <?php print_r($avgEuro)?>
    <?php }?>
    </div>

    <?php if($type == 'RUR') { ?>
        <div class="buy">
            <h3> Покупка </h3>
            <p><?php print_r($privatdata[1]["buy"])?></p>
            <p><?php print_r($nbudata[28]["rate"])?></p>
            <p><?php print_r($mejdata[2]["Buy"])?></p>
            <p><?php print_r($blackdata[2]["Buy"])?></p>
        </div>
        <div class="sale">
            <h3> Продажа </h3>
            <p><?php print_r($privatdata[1]["sale"])?></p>
            <p><?php print_r($nbudata[28]["rate"])?></p>
            <p><?php print_r($mejdata[2]["Sale"])?></p>
            <p><?php print_r($blackdata[2]["Sale"])?></p>
        </div>
        <div class="avg_rate">
            <h3>Средний курс на сегодня:</h3>
            <?php print_r($avgRUR)?>
        <?php }?>
        </div>
</div>
<div class="links">
<?= Html::a('USA', ['index.php/rates', 'type' => 'USA']) ?>
<?= Html::a('Euro', ['index.php/rates', 'type' => 'Euro']) ?>
<?= Html::a('RUR', ['index.php/rates', 'type' => 'RUR']) ?>
</div>
<style>
div {
    display: inline-block !important;
}
.avg_rate {
    vertical-align: top;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood right, you want to fix the height of a div? If so, just set the height you want in CSS:

```
height: 100px; 
max-height:100px;
```

Optionally you can use `overflow: auto`, to show scrollbars on the div

Comment: it doesn't help. I want to fix height and width and want to have one div including others.

Comment: to include a div on other div its just putting them in a hierarchical structure. sorry, i cant understand what you want, please, explain with more details